# Angular JS using XSOData

Tags: angularjs, odata, hana

Does `$format=json` and `$filter` work together in the Odata url?
My Odata url looks like this, however it did not work:
`http://host:port/xx/yy/aa/file.xsodata/RetrieveData/?$format=json/?$filter=STREET` eq 'Hereweg'.

Can you let me know which part of the syntax is going wrong. If this two works together, can anyone give me an example of the Odata url?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check [Understanding OData in 6 steps](http://www.odata.org/getting-started/understand-odata-in-6-steps/).
For your example the right syntax would probably be something like

```
http://host:port/xx/yy/aa/file.xsodata/RetrieveData/?$format=json &amp; $filter=STREET eq 'Hereweg'
```

Comment: Thanks..When I run the Odata using either $format or $filter , it works ..However when I try to use both together it does not work..I tried with your suggestion but its giving me an error as mentioned below :This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<code/>
<message xml:lang="en-US">
Invalid $format query option. The only acceptable values are 'json', 'atom', and 'xml'. Received value: 'json '.
</message>
</error>  ..Any suggestions?